# PHP while statement generating form but bootstrap column not working for the first item?

Tags: php, html

I am attempting to create 3 form fields for each of the products I have on my page. ID, Price, Box. For some reason ALL of the form input fields I generate after the first row appear to be aligned correctly but the first row is way out of whack.

[Click here for Image of column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvBqT.png)

As you can see (above) the first row is aligned strangely, Here is my PHP that echo's the HTML code to build the table and display the form.

```
    echo "<head>
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/bootstrap.css'>";
echo "</head>";
echo '<table class="table table-hover" table id="ResolvedTable" width="90%">'; // start a table tag in the HTML
echo "<thead><tr>
<th onclick='sortTableResolved(0)'><i class='fa fa-sort-desc' title='Sort Column.'><strong>ID#&nbsp;</strong></th>
<th onclick='sortTableResolved(1)'><i class='fa fa-sort-desc' title='Sort Column.'><strong>Name&nbsp;</strong></th>
<th onclick='sortTableResolved(2)'><i class='fa fa-sort-desc' title='Sort Column.'><strong>SKU</strong></th>
<th onclick='sortTableResolved(3)'><i class='fa fa-sort-desc' title='Sort Column.'><strong>Category</strong></th>
<th onclick='sortTableResolved(4)'><i class='fa fa-sort-desc' title='Sort Column.'><strong>Technician</strong></th>
<th onclick='sortTableResolved(5)'><i class='fa fa-sort-desc' title='Sort Column.'><strong>Test</strong></th>
</tr></thead>";
$numberofloops = 1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){   //Creates a loop to loop through results
$thisid = $row['productnumber'];
$totalloops = $numberofloops++;
$priceid = 'price' . $totalloops;
$boxid = 'box' . $totalloops;

echo "
<tbody><tr><td><a href='https://core.tradeit.guru/editproduct.php?editID="; echo $thisid . "' target='_blank'>" . $row['productnumber'] . "</a></td><td>" . $row['productname'] . "</td><td>" . $row['productsku'] . "</td><td>" . $row['productcategory'] . "</td><td>" . $row['technician'] . "</td><td>";

echo '<form class="form-inline" form action="/page.php" method="post">
<fieldset>

<!-- Product ID -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="editproductid">ID</label>
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <select id="editproductid" name="editproductid" class="form-control" readonly>
      <option value="';echo $thisid . '"">';echo $thisid . '</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="productidforform">Price</label>  
  <div class="col-md-8">
  <input id="productidforform" name="productidforform" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md">

  </div>
</div>

<!-- Select Basic -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="productidhere">Box</label>
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <select id="productidhere" name="productidhere" class="form-control">
      <option value="1">24" Monitors 66 x 51 x 16 cm 26"x 20"x 6"</option>
      <option value="2">AMX BOX 26 x 26 x 13 cm 10"x 10"x 5"</option>
      <option value="3">CellPhone box 21 x 16 x 11 cm 8" x 6" x 4"</option>
      <option value="4">CellPhone ENV 24 x 18 x 4 cm 9" x 7" x 2"</option>
      <option value="5">CellPhone Mailer 26 x 18 x 9 cm 10"x 7"x 3"</option>
      <option value="6">Desktop SMALL 46 x 41 x 16 cm 18" x 16" x 6"</option>
      <option value="7">Laptop 14" 15" 41 x 31 x 11 cm 16" x 12" x 4"</option>
      <option value="8">Projector - 51 x 41 x 21 cm - 20" x 16" x 8"</option>
      <option value="9">Square Box 21 x 21 x 21 cm 8"x 8"x 8"</option>
      <option value="10">Switch 51 x 46 x 11 cm 20" x 18" x 4"</option>
      <option value="11">Tablet 31 x 31 x 8 cm 12" x 12" x 3"</option>
      <option value="12">Variable Height 12" 30 x 30 x 30 cm 12"x 12"x 12"</option>
      <option value="13">Variable Height 18" 45 x 45 x 45 cm 18"x 18"x 18"</option>
      <option value="14">Variable Height 20" 50 x 50 x 50 cm 20"x 20"x 20"</option>
      <option value="15">Printer - Heavy duty 50 x 50 x 50 cm 20"x 20"x 20"</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>';

}
echo "</tbody></table>"; //Close the table in HTML
```

Comment: Need to see preceding code, starting before the `while(...)` that you mention

Comment: Please post the *rendered* HTML

Comment: Added the code that starts before the "while"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a form attribute in your form tag, isn't the issue coming from there ?

On top of this, your fieldset is never closed and your tbody and table never opened.

Comment: He's referring to the 2nd `form` in `<form class="form-inline" form action="/page.php" method="post">`, and that could possibly be the issue.

Comment: Wow, it was THAT simple. Amazing how you can read something over 20 times and miss what was right in front of your face.

THANK YOU.

Comment: @DragonKyn  That isn't the only issue: see my answer. You are also opening a `<tbody>` for every row.

Comment: And the fieldset that I can't find closure as well

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new `<tbody>` for every row, but you are only closing `</tbody>` after the loop ends (that part is correct, there should be only one `<tbody></tbody>` per table):

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
...
echo "
<tbody><tr><td><a href='https://core.tradeit.guru/editproduct.php?editID="; echo $thisid . "' target='_blank'>" . $row['productnumber'] . "</a></td><td>" . $row['productname'] . "</td><td>" . $row['productsku'] . "</td><td>" . $row['productcategory'] . "</td><td>" . $row['technician'] . "</td><td>";
```

The `<tbody>` should be opened before the loop starts:

```
...
</tr></thead>
<tbody>";
$numberofloops = 1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
```